# How to configure rout to serve all files from subfolder using httphandler in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have two websites in IIS under default web site. Lets say "Website1"       page gives call to "webiste2" which return some content.     Entry URL of website2 is http://domainname/websitename/controller/action this action return html(index.html). structure of website2 is as bellow.

```
Website
Folder(websitename)                                               
........Folder A(folder_{id}(id is dynamically generated) is under folder A)                                                                           
..............Folder_{id} --> this folder contains files with many extensions  
........Index.html->this file has references to above folderA &subfolders files            
........Web.config
```

Now i want to configure route such a way that that serve all types of files extensions for url like below.

1. `websitename/folder A/filename.abc`
2. `websitename/Folder A/folder_1/filename.xy`
3. `websitename/folder A/Folder_1/filename.mp3`
4. `websitename/folder A/Folder_1/filename.png`

There can be thousands folder under folder A. so the folder_1 value can be changed from `folder_1` to `folder_2`, `folder_3` .............. `folder_1000` or as many folders.
    I want generic rout to serve all dynamically generated folders and its files.
    There are many files with different extensions under these dynamically created folder or we can see its as package of different files like .mp3, ,jpg, .swf, .js...

Please guide me to write rout to achieve above. Or you can provide links so that i can go through.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, don't. Static files are supposed to be served directly by IIS. By default, in MVC, anything that has an extension (`.*`) is handled by IIS, and MVC is never even involved. If you've customized something, I'd recommend undoing that.